# IntelliJ does not recognize kotlin file after deleting it and recreate with the same name

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I am currently having a problem with IntelliJ. I am using Kotlin in my project. I have deleted a file (let's say test.kt), and now, I want to create a new file with the same name. IntelliJ does not recognize the kotlin syntaxe and show it as a text file.

When I have deleted I have unchecked "safe delete" and "Search in comment and strings"

Can anyone help me in this matter ?

Edit : I tried to delete .idea and .iml file, restart intelliJ. It does not change anything.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your directory layout in IDEA? With the description where you wanted to put that file. My point is that maybe you need to mark that directory as sources root.

Comment: Hi @MarošŠeleng, It is in Source directory. I have a file in the same repository, it is recognized as a kotlin file. I try to create with any other name thant test.kt, it works. My problem is only for the file I deleted.

Comment: I would try: File -> invalidate caches / restart.

Comment: Hi @sschrass ! Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly it does not work. I changed my file name for the moment in order not to be blocked by this problem.

Comment: Is `test.kt` listed in Preferences > Editor > File Types > Text, under the Registered Patterns? An entry there may override the default Kotlin filetype.

Comment: Same here, renaming the file correct the pb but renaming the file back and the pb is bask. Weird! Using Intellij 2018.1

Comment: Same problem, with the name "Given.kt" not recognized as a Kotlin file.

Comment: Had the same problem. Found the file under File Types as Text. Works fine after removing it from the list as per @JKLy suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

"Overrid File Type" to Kotlin would work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on a comment:

> Is test.kt listed in Preferences > Editor > File Types > Text, under the Registered Patterns? An entry there may override the default Kotlin filetype

I had a class, `MyProxy.kt`, that as the question implies was not being picked up as a Kotlin class in IntelliJ. I scrolled through my list of file associations and did not find anything that could match `MyProxy.kt` except for the Kotlin extension, `*.kt` (it is entirely possible I missed something.)

Most regex matching will apply the most specific rule, though. On the off chance my class was being picked up by another association, I explicitly declared it as a Kotlin file pattern. It is a little hacky, but it did work! My Kotlin file name patterns are now:

```
*.kt
*.kts
*.main.kts
MyProxy.kt
```

> *Note: IntelliJ did complain that `*.kt` would already catch `MyProxy.kt`, but I overrode it.*

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+alt+s, Editor, File Types, under recognized filetypes,
Under Filetype auto-detected by file content...
remove Main.kt

[image: screenshot]